# Mutating a "rich" character vector into multiple variable denoting presence of their element

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I'm currently cleaning some survey data where there are variables with multiple responses in each. For instance, respondents endorse all elements that apply and they all get stored in one variable e.x., "Dogs, Cats, Rhinos". A reproducible example of one such variable is given below:

```
library(dplyr); library(magrittr)
set.seed(42)

foo <- data.frame(x = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5],
                               size = runif(1, min = 0, max = 5),
                               replace = F) %>% paste0(collapse = ", "),
                        sample(LETTERS[1:5],
                               size = runif(1, min = 0, max = 5),
                               replace = F) %>% paste0(collapse = ", ")))
```

What I'm looking to accomplish is to decompose the elements a variable and have new variables denoting the presence (or lack) of a given element. In this case my separator for elements would be a comma. An example of the intended output given below.

```
fooWant <- data.frame("A" = c(1, 0), "B" = c(1, 1), "D" = c(1, 0), "E" = c(1, 1))
```

So far my progress hasn't been great and I've just accomplished at parsing the elements into nested lists (code below) and am hoping that someone can take me the rest of the way there. Thanks a ton :)

```
strsplit(foo$x %>% as.character, split = "[,]\\s?") %>% sapply(X = ., sort)
```

Comment: using your progress, you could do: `strsplit(foo$x %>% as.character, split = "[,]\\s?")%>%set_names(seq_along(.))%>%stack%>%table%>%t%>%as.data.frame.matrix`

Comment: `splitstackshape::cSplit_e(foo, "x", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution using `tidyr::separate_rows` and `tidyr::spread`

```
foo %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    separate_rows(x) %>%
    mutate(n = 1) %>%
    spread(x, n, fill = 0) %>%
    select(-row)
#  A B D E
#1 1 1 1 1
#2 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: There is a lot of overhead with calling that many functions to separate the string with multiple choices into individual entities. This solution is fairly slow compared to a simple `str_count` call on the `data.frame`.

Comment: @BenjaminYe - I'd try it on larger data too. This solution runs 4x faster than yours by my testing on 100K rows.

Comment: @thelatemail I tried it using `rbenchmark` and you're absolutely correct! Looks like it depends on what Maurits is trying to do, as it seems to be significantly faster for <100 items but much slower for >1000 items.

Comment: @BenjaminYe *"Looks like it depends on what Maurits is trying to do"* Hmm, what have I missed? I'm not "trying to do" anything; my answer provides a fairly `tidyverse`-centric and syntactically straight-forward solution to OPs problem statement. Your benchmark results seem to contradict thelatemail's results.

Comment: @MauritsEvers My apologies, I mistook your username for the original poster of the question. I don't believe I deserved the condescending response over a simple mix-up like this.

Comment: @BenjaminYe There is absolutely no condescension in my response. You fail to miss my point. Your benchmark results contradict those from thelatemail. I imagine that your approach will be a lot slower for large data (according to thelatemail by a factor of 4). Which would make sense because string operations such as `str_count` are costly for large input vectors.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
set.seed(42)
foo <- data.frame(
  x = c(
    sample(
      LETTERS[1:5], 
      size = runif(1, min = 0, max = 5), 
      replace = F
    ) %>% 
      paste0(collapse = ", "),
    sample(
      LETTERS[1:5], 
      size = runif(1, min = 0, max = 5), 
      replace = F
    ) %>% 
      paste0(collapse = ", "))
  )
foo[, LETTERS[1:5]] <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    foo$x,
    function (df) {
      str_count(df, LETTERS[1:5])
    } 
  )
)
```

`str_count` counts the number of occurrences of the possible values and appends them on as columns to the right of the original data.

```
> foo
           x A B C D E
1 E, A, D, B 1 1 0 1 1
2       B, E 0 1 0 0 1
```

Here it is again, but as a `tibble` to more clearly see the columns:

```
> library(tibble); as_tibble(foo)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  x              A     B     C     D     E
  <fct>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 E, A, D, B     1     1     0     1     1
2 B, E           0     1     0     0     1
```